Is "sharp" a correct synomym for "acute" in the phrase "an acute angle"?
In my native language, Dutch, we only have one word for an angle of less than 90 degrees: "scherp". Therefore, we usually translate this as "sharp", as in "a sharp angle". I guess a native speaker of English might prefer "an acute angle", but I am wondering whether "sharp angle" isn't a false friend?

Sharp is a good word to describe acute angles, and not a false friend. However, math as written in English uses the specialized word acute, that's all.

'Acute angle' is a fixed phrase (the term appears in many dictionaries, along with 'right angle' and 'obtuse angle') whereas I'd class 'sharp angle' as a weak collocation at best. And in everyday usage, I'd say that a 'sharp angle' is usually an angle of less than 30°.

But we would definitely say take a sharp right for an acute angle in the road.

Are you talking about mathematics, or everyday life (e.g. bends, corners, turns, changes of direction, edges)?

Ngrams shows that "acute angle" is twice more frequent than "sharp angle".

Also, perspective is a good synonym for angle, but not in math. Cute is almost acute, but not in math. Sharp is spelled almost like shark, but it won't come back to bite you. Math people don't make up vocabulary as they go along.

Sharp angle is not an expression suitable for mathematical or technical writing, but in a non-technical setting, it's a fairly good synonym for acute angle.

A sharp angle in common usage is not the same as an acute angle. There are various related uses of sharp given in Merriam-Webster from which we can extract:

"adapted to cutting or piercing: such as having a thin keen edge or fine point"
"terminating in a point or edge"
"involving an abrupt or marked change especially in direction"

When dealing with a corner or an edge, the meanings given above come into play. If you encounter a sharp angle on a road or object, it will be abrupt or pointed (not rounded or gentle). Typically it will have an angle significantly less than 90 degrees, but it's possible to make a "sharp turn" when driving even if you turn a right angle, as long as you do it with the steering wheel turned far enough.
Quality of the turn or edge
One sense of "sharp" refers to an abrupt turn, with a small turning radius. WordReference.com defines a "sharp turn" as an "abrupt curve in a road".
In driving, a contrast is often made between a "wide turn", i.e. a gradual curve that can be made at a high speed, and a "sharp turn", with a much more sudden change of direction and lower speed, even if both are at the same junction.
Angle substantially less than 90 degrees
Another common meaning is of an angle substantially less than 90 degrees: maybe below 45 or 60 degrees.
The EU air traffic control aviation EUROCONTROL defines a "sharp turn angle" as a turn of more than 120 degrees, i.e. an angle of 60 degrees or less to the preceding flight path.
A discussion in Quora sees someone suggesting 45 degrees or less is sharp, above 60 degrees is not sharp, and the rest are debatable.
Both
A sharp-edged weapon is one capable of cutting, which typically requires an angle much less than 90 degrees, and a fine edge rather than a gently rounded rim.
Acute and sharp are only synonymous in the sense of having sharp or acute powers of discrimination. M-W again: "sharp, keen, acute mean having or showing alert competence and clear understanding."

I'm sorry to point out that in common usage, a sharp angle clearly is the same as an acute angle.
